# How to reimplement AsmPrinter in LLVM-Clang to generate my own directive set?

Tags: c, assembly, clang, llvm

I'm using LLVM and Clang to generate assembly listing from .c file. Instructions are printed correctly, but in the beginning and in the end LLVM-Clang inserts default directives incompatible with my architecture. I overrode AsmPrinter class to get own directives, but I succeeded only in adding new directives not in replacing them. For instance:

MyAsmPrinter.c:

```
class MyAsmPrinter : public AsmPrinter { 
...
    void EmitStartOfAsmFile(Module &M) override;
    void EmitEndOfAsmFile(Module &M) override;
...
}

void MyAsmPrinter::EmitStartOfAsmFile(Module &M) {
    <--- insert something (A)
}

void MyAsmPrinter::EmitEndOfAsmFile(Module &M) {
    <--- insert something (B)
}
```

clangtest.c:

```
int main() 
{
  int a, b;
  b = 3;
  a = b*b;
  return a;
}
```

I type:

```
./bin/clang -target mytarget -S clangtest.c -o test.s
```

And get

```
.text
<--- (A goes here)
.file   "clangtest.c"
.globl  main
.type   main,@function
    main:
    (correct asm code here)
.Ltmp0:
    .size   main, .Ltmp0-main


.ident  "clang version 3.6.0 ..."
.section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
<--- (B goes here)
```

But I want to get rid of ".text", ".file" and ".ident" at all. Where they get inserted anyway? I tried googling it, greping source code for other targets and LLVM source code, but found nothing. So, could anyone give me a hint how to do this?

Comment: Related: Matt Godbolt has written nice filters to filter out "boring" asm lines, instead of modifying compilers to not print them in the first place.[How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)